# Tensorflow training accuracy and loss different from evaluation of the same dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I try to train a Tensorflow model with two classes.
My Trainingsdata is balanced (~11k images for both classes).
I am using Tranferlearning and try to continue on the InceptionV3 Model with the following code:

```
BUFFER_SIZE = 1000
BATCH_SIZE = 32

def get_label(file_path, class_names):
  # convert the path to a list of path components
  parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
  # The second to last is the class-directory
  return parts[-2] == class_names

def parse_image(filename):
    parts = tf.strings.split(filename, "\\")
    label = get_label(filename, CLASS_NAMES)

    image = tf.io.read_file(filename)
    image = tf.image.decode_png(image, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [299,299])/255.0
    return image, label

datasetFilePath = "Path\To\BalancedData"
IMAGESIZE = 299
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
datasetPath = pathlib.Path(datasetFilePath)
list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(datasetPath/"*/*"))

CLASS_NAMES = np.array([item.name for item in datasetPath.glob('*')])

# labeled_ds = list_ds.map(process_path)

images_ds = list_ds.map(parse_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
images_ds = images_ds.shuffle(BATCH_SIZE)

dataset = images_ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)

for image_batch, label_batch in dataset.take(1):
    pass

def build_and_compile_model():
    base_model =tf.keras.applications.InceptionV3(include_top=False, weights = "imagenet", input_shape=(IMAGESIZE,IMAGESIZE,3))
    feature_batch = base_model(image_batch)
    print(feature_batch.shape)

    base_model.trainable = False
    x = base_model.output
    x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(name="avg_pool")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(x)
    predictions = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax")(x)
    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

    base_learning_rate = 0.00001
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=base_learning_rate),
                 loss="categorical_crossentropy",
                 metrics=["accuracy"])
    return model


multi_worker_model = build_and_compile_model()
tensorboard = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir, histogram_freq=1)
history = multi_worker_model.fit(dataset, epochs=2, callbacks=[tensorboard])

=>Epoch 1/2
=>711/711 [==============================] - 176s 247ms/step - loss: 0.3309 - accuracy: 0.8945
=>Epoch 2/2
=>711/711 [==============================] - 166s 233ms/step - loss: 0.1410 - accuracy: 0.9632

predictions = multi_worker_model.evaluate(dataset)
=>711/711 [==============================] - 150s 212ms/step - loss: 0.7538 - accuracy: 0.4999
```

So all in all my model just predicts everything to be of class 1 and i dont understand why that is and mostly why it claims to have a training accuracy of 96%

It might be a problem of the Data, but then again, i would expect a training accuracy of also ~50% as both training and evaluation happen on the same dataset.

Any help would be much appreciated and if you need more information let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a few more hours of reseach i might have the Problem.
InceptionV3 uses

```
def preprocess_input(x):
    x /= 255.
    x -= 0.5
    x *= 2.
    return x
```

as preprocess function. And i am only doing the x/=255 part wich is not enough. The difference of the accuracy might be because in the `.fit` function automatically does the preprocess, the `.evaluate` on the other hand cant do that.

I am not 100% sure that this is the correct answer, but its my best guess. And it also works with setting the `base_model.trainable = False` to `base_model.trainable = True`. I think this allows the model to train with my own preprocessing and so the evaluation works also, because it gets my preprocessing.

I hope this might help someone with a similar problem. But i am still glad for any input from people who might give a better insight into the topic.